# Searching with .NET MVC with two models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am very new to .NET MVC and have been followed [these tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search). I am starting to try and build something for myself and referring back to the tutorial for guidance.

While trying to implement a search feature I am struggling to get the second search box to work.  I have two models, Profile and Category:

```
public class Profile {

    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have my first search working fine, which takes a text input and searches against the Profile Location Property.  However I would like to add a second search that get a list of All the categories in a drop down and the user would be able to search based on category.  Here is the controller code that I have so far:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchCategory, string searchString)
    {
        var CategoryList = new List<string>();

        var CategoryQuery = from d in db.Categories
                            orderby d.Name
                            select d.Name;

        CategoryList.AddRange(CategoryQuery.Distinct());
        ViewBag.searchCategory = new SelectList(CategoryList);

        var profiles = from p in db.Profiles
                       select p;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) {
            profiles = profiles.Where(x => x.Location.Contains(searchString));
        }

//**This is where I cannot figure out the right lambda expression
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCategory)) {
            profiles = profiles.Where(x => x.Categories.Contains(y => y.Name.Find(searchCategory)));
        }

        return View(profiles); 
    }
```

I am very new to lambda expressions, and in the second if statement, I know I am doing something very wrong but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code inside second `if` to this

```
profiles.Where(x => x.Categories.Any(y => y.Name==searchCategory));
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<SelectListItem>` provides access to drop down list binding:

```
// model class
public class ModelClass
{
    public List<SelectListItem> DropDownValues { get; set; }
}
```

Pass `List<Category>` values into `List<SelectListItem>`:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCategory)) {
    // Equals ensure value comparison instead of possible reference
    profiles = profiles.Where(x => x.Categories.Any(y => y.Name.Equals(searchCategory));

    DropDownValues = new List<SelectListItem>();

    // iterate through category list and pass values to SelectListItem
    foreach (Categories cat in profiles) {
        DropDownValues.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = cat.Name, Value = cat.Value });
    }
}
```

CSHTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Value, ModelClass.DropDownValues);
```

Hope this solution helped a lot.